# Clone repo inside docker volume with devcontainer, re-open it and access it's ip

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote, vscode-devcontainer, devcontainer

**First** trouble is how to re-open a cloned repo inside a volume with Remote container's option:

**"Clone repository in named container volume"**

It creates the volume inside a container, i can use it exacly how i wanted inside it, but if i close this vscode window, how do i get back to this volume and continue working?

---

**Second** issue i'm having is with the ip for this created volume. I cloned an application that is accessible by other applications (i run all of them locally) but when i try to access the app created by the docker volume it just does'nt find this ip and have trouble connecting.

What have i tried: access "localhost", access the local machine ip, access the ip provided by "ifconfig" inside the docker volume.

---

Steps followed: *Clone repository in named container volume* > *Try to connect the cloned inside this volume*

Comment: This might help with your first issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67156072/vscode-how-to-open-repositories-that-have-been-cloned-to-a-local-volume

Answer (score 0):

**For question #1:** you can access a container created with the option `Clone Repository in Container Volume` in three ways:

- from the *Open Recent* menu: `Ctrl+Shift+P` > `File: Open Recent`, from the *File* menu or the *Recent* list in the *welcome page*.
- cloning again the same repository, as it will not create a new volume and use the existing one (note, however, that if you change branch, vscode will clone the default one, which will not work).
- from the *Remote Explorer* or *Docker* panel: find your project in the container list and then `right click` > `Start` and then `Attach Visual Studio Code` for Docker or `right click` > `Open Folder in Container` for the Remote Explorer.

---

**For question #2:** it depends on what you are trying to do.

- If you want to access the services of the container from your host machine: check that your service is accessible from `localhost`, from your browser at the port you specified. If it is not, you have to [forward the ports](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers#_forwarding-or-publishing-a-port) you are using. Keep in mind that you can map a port of the container to a different port of the host, this can cause some confusion.
- If you want to access the services of your host machine (or of another container that is accessible from it) from the container: you must use `host.docker.internal` as your URL, as explained [here](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/networking/#i-want-to-connect-from-a-container-to-a-service-on-the-host).
- If you want to access the services of a container from another container, without exposing the ports to the host: you can use [docker-compose](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/create-dev-container#_use-docker-compose) and use as URL the name of the service.